# MYSQL/PHP Select same values

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

I have a table with products, which I can order.

```
╔═════════╦═════════╗
║ ORDERID ║ INSTORE ║
╠═════════╬═════════╣
║       1 ║       0 ║
║       1 ║       1 ║
║       1 ║       1 ║
║       1 ║       1 ║
║       1 ║       0 ║
║       2 ║       1 ║
║       2 ║       1 ║
║       2 ║       1 ║
╚═════════╩═════════╝
```

Now I need to get all orders with instore all having value 1, Like orderid2.
How is this possible?

Desired Result

```
╔═════════╗
║ ORDERID ║
╠═════════╣
║       2 ║
╚═════════╝
```

Comment: SELECT *
    FROM products
    WHERE instore = 1; ?

Comment: Do you mean this? `SELECT * FROM products WHERE orderid NOT IN (SELECT orderid FROM products WHERE instore <> 1)`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  orderID
FROM    tableName
GROUP   BY orderID
HAVING  COUNT(*) = SUM(instore = 1)
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/79bb0/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM products p WHERE not exists (select 1 from products where orderid = p.orderid and instore != 1 limit 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I completely understand your question but

```
select * from products where instore=1 and orderid=2;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT (
```

OrderID
)
FROM  `products` 
WHERE Instore =1
AND OrderID NOT 
IN (

SELECT OrderID
FROM products
WHERE  `Instore` =0
)